# Binary Tree To Mathematical Expression

Tags: c#, math, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree that contain a mathematical expression. I use array for save binary tree in memory.
I save operators(like + or tan) as string in array. for every i node, left node index is 2*i+1 and right node index is 2*i+2. every node can be operand or operator. I want to convert binary tree to a mathematical expression as string like: **"2+tan(tan(10))"** . how can convert a binary tree to mathematical expression in c#?

```
  +
 / \
2  tan
   / \               ===>      "2+tan(tan(10))"
 tan  
 / \ / \
10
```

this my binary tree code:

```
public class Tree
{
    private readonly List<Node> _nodes;

    public Tree(int size)
    {
        _nodes = new List<Node>();

        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            _nodes.Add(new Node(i, null));
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (2*i+1 > size-1 || 2*i+2 > size-1)
                break;

            _nodes[i].Left = _nodes[2*i + 1];
            _nodes[i].Right = _nodes[2*i + 2];
        }
    }
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it recursively - write a method that returns a string, and does these three things:

- When both subtrees are null, return the content of the node
- When only one subtrees is non-null, call the method recursively, and then return the content of the node followed by the result from the recursive call in parentheses
- When both subtrees are non-null, make recursive calls for the left and the rift subtrees, and return the left result followed by the content of this node followed by the right result.

Comment: tnx, can u write the pseudocode of your recursive function?

Comment: This is called in-order tree traversal. You must remember though that various operators have different precedence and in infix notation you might have to use parentheses.

Comment: @ArMaN I can't write pseudo code at the moment, because I'm on an iPhone :) I may be able to write some when I get back to a computer, though.

Comment: @Grx70 Right, I assume that the precedence is "baked into" the tree structure already.